# Magento 2 : On clicking swatches, thumbnail images are hiding

Tags: magento2.2.6, product-page

On product page, On clicking swatches Size and color. Thumbnail images are hiding.Why is it so happening. I used custom theme. Please help somone.

Comment: Can you share your url?

Comment: its on my local machine

Comment: @twinkle_gupta, did you manage tor resolve this issue?